# built-in method ravel of numpy.ndarray object... insead of the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, pretty-print

I want to convert some images to numpy arrays, and pretty-print them. I have stored all the images in an array of numpy arrays.

```
path = "greyset/"
vector_classwise = [[0 for i in range(200)] for j in range(10)]

for image_path in os.listdir(path):
    inpath = os.path.join(path, image_path)
    img = Image.open(inpath)
    arr = np.array(img)
    shape = arr.shape
    flat_arr = arr.ravel
    vector = np.matrix(flat_arr)

    #image_path is of the form classname_image_number

    class_num = int(image_path[0:3])
    entry = int(image_path[4:7])

    vector_classwise[class_num][entry] = vector

print (vector_classwise[3][5])
```

However, when I try printing the last line, I get

```
[[<built-in method ravel of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7ff472a84490>]]
```

instead of the array.

I tried writing this:

```
print (vector_classwise[3][5]())
```

to call the method as one of the answers suggested, but I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'matrix' object is not callable
```

How can I print out the vectors in the array vector_classwise?

Comment: Try using `arr.ravel()` (with parentheses, so the method is actually called) instead of `arr.ravel`?

Comment: @sacul it worked, thank you!